# osxkeychain is not storing github credentials?

Tags: git, github, keychain, macos-high-sierra

Background:
I have 2FA set up in my Github account. I cloned a repo using https. I am trying to use git credential helper to store the github creds (username and Personal Access Token) so that I don't have to enter them on every git push/pull.

I followed the steps here https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/ to store the github credentials in the Keychain Access app. However, when I do a git clone, I was asked my creds. After that when I searched the Keychain Access app for "github.com", there was no entry. So when I tried to do a `git push` in that repo, I was asked my github credentials again.

Why aren't my credentials being stored in the keychain app even after following the credential helper?

My OS is MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4.

Comment: Try running `GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` - it will show what credential helper commands are being run

Comment: @rbennett485 I tried it and it is trying to run `git credential-osxkeychain get`. But the problem is the the credentials don't exist in the keychain at all.

Comment: Does it do a `git credential-osxkeychain store` after you type your password? That's the bit that should save it

Comment: Hi, I am also experiencing this kind of issue. I tried `GET_TRACE=1 git pull`, and after writing password, it does run `10:32:53.145811 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: 'git credential-osxkeychain store'
10:32:53.172351 git.c:669               trace: exec: git-credential-osxkeychain store`. But no entry on keychain. Any idea on this?

Comment: To me it was tmux. When I was in a tmux session, `store` command somehow did not actually store the credential in the keychain. I have to be on a *bare* bash session once to store the credential, and after that `get` works just fine even in a tmux session.

Answer (score 13):

I experienced this issue this week. Where I keep on inputting username & password every time I do `git pull`.

After checking to the net, there were couple of options. [See here](https://help.queens.edu/hc/en-us/articles/205937040-How-to-Resolve-Mac-OS-X-Keychain-Problems)

I did not look into the details deeply. Unknowingly, I went to my **Keychain Access** and did these steps:

1. If you click on the `lock icon` 
   [image: Keychain Access Interface]
2. I clicked on it, making it locked
   [image: Locked keychain access]
3. I tried running `git pull` again and prompted with `git-credential-osxkeychain` asking for login password.
   [image: git-credential-osxkeychain prompt]
4. And lastly, I successfully pulled updates

```sh
MB-0018:laravel joseph$ git pull
Already up to date.
MB-0018:laravel joseph$
```

That's all. Hope this applies to you.